# How to install Sagemath on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, sagemath

Why do the installation of Sagemath fails on Ubuntu? I tried

```
jaakko@jaakko-Aspire-E1-572:~$ sudo apt install sagemath-common
[sudo] password for jaakko: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sagemath-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 16,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 205 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 sagemath-common all 9.0-1ubuntu4 [16,2 MB]
Fetched 16,2 MB in 4s (3 888 kB/s)            
Selecting previously unselected package sagemath-common.
(Reading database ... 216481 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sagemath-common_9.0-1ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking sagemath-common (9.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up sagemath-common (9.0-1ubuntu4) ...
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/combinat/root_system/branching_rules.py:1753
: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if len(stypes) is not 2:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/graphs/graph_latex.py:1159: SyntaxWarning: '
str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError('%s option must be a dictionary, not %s' (name, value))
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/graphs/graph_latex.py:1168: SyntaxWarning: '
str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError('%s option must be a dictionary, not %s' (name, value))
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/graphs/graph_latex.py:1175: SyntaxWarning: '
str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError('%s option must be a dictionary, not %s' (name, value))
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/graphs/graph_latex.py:1182: SyntaxWarning: '
str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError('%s option must be a dictionary, not %s' (name, value))
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/graphs/graph_latex.py:1189: SyntaxWarning: '
str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError('%s option must be a dictionary, not %s' (name, value))
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/graphs/graph_latex.py:1196: SyntaxWarning: '
str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError('%s option must be a dictionary, not %s' (name, value))
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/graphs/graph_latex.py:1203: SyntaxWarning: '
str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError('%s option must be a dictionary, not %s' (name, value))
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
jaakko@jaakko-Aspire-E1-572:~$ sage
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 9.0, Release Date: 2020-01-01                     │
│ Using Python 3.8.5. Type "help()" for help.                        │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/sagemath/bin/sage-ipython", line 12, in <module>
    from sage.repl.interpreter import SageTerminalApp
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/repl/interpreter.py", line 105, in <module>
    from sage.repl.preparse import preparse, containing_block
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/repl/preparse.py", line 227, in <module>
    from sage.repl.load import load_wrap
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/repl/load.py", line 19, in <module>
    from sage.cpython.string import str_to_bytes, bytes_to_str, FS_ENCODING
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage.cpython.string'
jaakko@jaakko-Aspire-E1-572:~$
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy python-is-python2 python-is-python3` ; `which python; which python2; which python3` to the question.

Comment: It is not necessary. The solution was to install sagemath instead of sagemath-common.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To install Sage Math, enter the command `sudo apt install sagemath`.

`sagemath-common` (which you installed) is one of the many dependencies of the whole package. When you install `sagemath`, it would automatically install all the required dependencies.

Comment: That install takes a whopping 3.5 GB of disk space. Is all of that needed, or can a core subset be downloaded, perhaps via pip?

Comment: I guess this is a path towards an answer to my question above on installing subsets of sage: [#29705 (Meta-ticket: Modularize sagelib into separate distributions (pip-installable packages) sagemath) – Sage](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/29705)

Answer (score 0):

It is now recommended to use 9.7 or higher version (https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/linux.html)

so i found this [guide](https://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/install_ubuntu.html) which helped me install and run SageMath in Jupyter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).